# My jquery has stopped working

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

My .js file seems to have stopped showing any results and I'm not sure why it has stopped working? I have removed any wordpress plugins that I had added thinking they might have been conflicted but that doesn't seem to have made any difference.

You can see my website here http://mhutchinson.me.uk/

As you can see, if you scroll down, the masonry script and the text replacement for the category has stopped working which are on the same .js file.

The file can be found here  http://mhutchinson.me.uk/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/script.js

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your console, as pointed out earlier, the issue is a JS error on line 31 where you are trying to call carousel.

The problem is that you are calling the carousel as the page is loaded, which in your case, is before .carousel as a DOM element has been loaded.

JS/Jquery best practices state that you put all your code that has dependancies on DOM elements in a window.onload handler, or in the case of jquery, use ready.

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel('cycle')({
    interval: 1000
  })
}
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel('cycle')({
    interval: 1000
  })
})
```

upon further investigation, the issue is conflicting libraries using $.  jQuery.noConflict should be used.
[jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Ive tried both versions and neither has fixed the problem of the JS loading. It was working perfectly fine but now seems to stop working and I cant figure out why ?

Comment: oh, simple syntax error on my case.  Update the jquery example.  had the closing ) in stead of  }).  Bear in mind, the error console will point these out FYI...

Comment: Okay I have updated the closing }) but I have a very basic knowledge of jquery. It still doesn't seem to have fixed the problem and ive checked the firebig console and its saying the cycle is not a function. Would any of this all of a sudden be breaking my other .js file?

Comment: ok, the issue is that you are using another library for your carousel, which also uses the $.  you would want to implement jQuery.noConflict http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: ive removed all jquery using the carousel and this still hasn't fixed my .js file? So it cant be a conflict issue can it? As ive removed anything for it to conflict with.

Comment: ok.  its still the same issue.  it looks like you are including the JS for maasonry before the DOM element has loaded.  Try putting the masonry code (starting with var $container) in $(document).ready()

Comment: Brilliant! Thats the one! Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console in Chrome (F12) or Firebug to view Javascript errors.  In this case it is `Uncaught Type Error:  object is not a function` relating to this piece of code you've added to your head;

```
 <script>
   $('.carousel').carousel('cycle')({
   interval: 1000
   })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the carousel first and then chaining on the `cycle` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000
    }).carousel('cycle');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I am only getting two errors when I load the page:

1. 404 not found on http://mhutchinson.me.uk/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
2. GET is failing on https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js (because Google +1 is blocked by my AVG browser extension)

and the `carousel` has stopped working (because the script is no longer on the page, or linked to the page as an external .js file).

Comment: I tried this and I think it got rid of the errors, but it still doesn't seem to be loading my other .js file. Any other thoughts on why it might not be working?